# Need to Create Multiple Identical Entities using RestKit

Tags: core-data, restkit, nsmanagedobject

I'm downloading often identical data on multiple calls to different URLs in RESTKit. The first call maps fine, but the subsequent calls then replace the first call's entities.

The behaviour that I want is to have the objects unique to within their parent entity, so even if the data looks the same I still want a new object to be created, but at the moment it looks like RESTKit wants them to be unique across the entire database. There's no unique key to do this in the data I'm downloading, the objects are literally identical. Below is the code I'm using to create the operation. How do I set this up to allow duplicates?

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [self requestWithURL:URL];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

RKHTTPRequestOperation *requestOperation = [[RKHTTPRequestOperation alloc]initWithRequest:request];

RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [INKResponseDescriptorFactory journeySegmentDescriptorForPath:URL.path inStore:[RKObjectManager sharedManager].managedObjectStore];

RKManagedObjectRequestOperation *operation = [[RKManagedObjectRequestOperation alloc] initWithHTTPRequestOperation:requestOperation
                                                                                               responseDescriptors:@[responseDescriptor]];

operation.managedObjectContext = [self.objectManager context];
operation.managedObjectCache = self.objectManager.managedObjectStore.managedObjectCache;
operation.savesToPersistentStore = NO;

[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess: ^(RKObjectRequestOperation *requestOperation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult)
{   
    success();
} failure: ^(RKObjectRequestOperation *requestOperation, NSError *error) {
    failure(error);
}];

[self.objectManager enqueueObjectRequestOperation:operation];
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a way to do this.

Each time I'm updating the data, even though the entities I get contain identical data, I'm retrieving them from a different url.

RESTKit allows you to retrieve metadata from you calls and map this into your managed objects properties.

So what I've done is map the URL I used for the request into a property and used that as well as an identifier, which is unique within this call's returned objects, to make objects which will be unique throughout the database.

So my mapping now looks like this:

```
RKEntityMapping *seatMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Seat" inManagedObjectStore:store];
[seatMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{ @"designator" : @"designator",
                                                   @"status" : @"status",
                                                   @"@metadata.HTTP.request.URL" : @"requestURL"}];

seatMapping.identificationAttributes = @[@"requestURL", @"designator"];
```

Comment: An alternative would be to remove `operation.managedObjectCache = self.objectManager.managedObjectStore.managedObjectCache;`, but then you would need to deal with any unintended duplicates.